# <column> IS NULL vs <column> = NULL in LINQ to SQL generated SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, null

in ASP.NET MVC 2.0 I'm doing something like the below (specifically, matching a record based on some values as well as some NULL values).

```
var result = dataContext.Inventory
 .SingleOrDefault(x => (x.part_id == model.Part.id &&
                        x.location_id == transaction.to_location_id &&
                        x.bin_id == transaction.to_bin_id &&
                        x.project_id == transaction.project_id &&
                        x.expiration_date == inventoryToTransfer.expiration_date));
```

...which returns `null`. I know the record exists, but the generated SQL (if I turn SQL Logging on) is

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[part_id], etc...
FROM [dbo].[Inventory] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Parts] AS [t1] ON [t1].[id] = [t0].[part_id]
WHERE ([t0].[part_id] = @p0) AND (([t0].[location_id]) = @p1) AND ([t0].[bin_id] = @p2) AND
([t0].[project_id] = @p3) AND ([t0].[expiration_date] = @p4)
-- @p0: Input BigInt (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [5197]
-- @p1: Input BigInt (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [57]
-- @p2: Input BigInt (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [71]
-- @p3: Input BigInt (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- @p4: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
```

Which in fact will return nothing as a comparison of  = NULL will return no matches. What I was thinking is that this would generate  IS NULL (which works great). Like this...

```
...
([t0].[project_id] IS NULL) AND ([t0].[expiration_date] IS NULL)
```

What am I missing with this? I believe I could turn on ANSI_NULLS in SQL Server but this is deprecated and there must be an easier way.

I know, I know... I shouldn't be defining uniqueness with NULL values, but is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you sure this isnt Linq-to-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `object.equals` to help ensure that the query returns is null

http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/LINQ-to-SQL-Null-check-in-Where-Clause.aspx

or

change the where for the nullable items to `((variable == null && x.column == null) || (x.column == variable))`

http://blog.linqexchange.com/index.php/how-to-use-is-null-with-linq-to-sql/

Comment: Works like a charm! -- the object.Equals() feels a little clunky but it's better than anything else. Then again, this is rare to require uniqueness on NULLs. Many thanks!